# Phoenix deployment exrm, letsencrypt freebsd

Tags: elixir, freebsd, phoenix-framework, lets-encrypt, exrm

I want to deploy phoenix application to digital ocean's FreeBSD server, however I am a little bit confused with all these new technologies. I am also a newbie at deployment. I used heroku before but never "really deployed" :)

So here is a list of what I currently do:
1) downloaded virtualbox
2) created and configured FreeBSD similarly to server so that exrm runs in the same environment
3) run `letsencrypt-auto certonly --config /etc/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.ini` with `letsencrypt.ini` being

```
rsa-key-size = 4096
email = example@email.com
domains = yourdomain.com, www.yourdomain.com
text = True
authenticator = webroot
standalone-supported-challenges = tls-sni-01
webroot-path = /src/isafe/priv/static
```

This was stolen from [this post](https://medium.com/@a4word/phoenix-app-secured-with-let-s-encrypt-469ac0995775#.82wyc3azr)
4) change phoenix app to support https
5) package release with exrm and send tar to production server

So the questions are:

1) Do I need to run letsencrypt on production server or what I do is fine?
2) It seems there is a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216626/elixir-phoenix-production-server-has-issue-with-letsencrypt-renewal) with elixir/phoenix and letsencrypt. What would be suggestions here? Should I may be not use letsencrypt
3) Is there anything else I am missing

Comment: I don't have really an answer to your questions about letsencrypt but have you read the deployment guides over at phoenixframework.org? Mainly this one: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/advanced-deployment

Comment: comment to follow the issue :)

Comment: https://excasts.com/episodes/exrm-release-for-a-simple-elixir-project and https://excasts.com/episodes/exrm-release-for-a-simple-phoenix-project

Comment: @SashaFonseca thanks for the link, good resource

Comment: @JasonHarrelson Thanks for links, but they are too simple, need more advanced